# How do I get my Ubuntu computer boot after last update made it un-bootable?

Tags: boot, drivers

How do I get my Ubuntu computer to, once again, boot?  The most recent update of my Ubuntu software caused my computer to be unbootable.  I ran the boot repair feature from the original installation DVD and this report/link was generated:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24122887/

The repair process did not appear to help at all.  During the process there was a pop-up screen with the following message: Grub-pc purge cancelled. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

This computer is a Dell Optiplex 330 with 4 GB of RAM (two 2 GB).  Recent OS version is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (16.04).  I can boot to the (old) installation DVD and I can get to a grub prompt.

The wireless adapter is:

02:00.0 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation Netlink BCM5787 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:169b] (rev 02)

(The only similar failure on the web was caused and fixed by a change in the driver for the wireless adapter. How do I restore/change Broadcom driver with un-bootable system?)

The "fsck" command did not help. One page of text messages result after the failed boot.  One final message is "Kernel panic - not synching: Fatal exception in interrupt".

ADDED 3/19/17: I reinstalled Ubuntu from the old installation disk and it ran fine.  I created an up to date Ubuntu 16.04.2 DVD and then re-formatted the drive and installed that.  That worked fine except that wireless networking no longer works.  It fairly clear that the old wireless adapter "Broadcom Corporation Netlink BCM5787" is not really supported anymore.  The driver "TIGON3" may solve this, but I have not pursued this fully.